# #fullcalendar how can i change the weekly times (0:00-24:00) to only (9:00 - 18:00)?

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

[AngularUI Calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) and [Arshaw FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

I'm using this ui-calendar.
The weekly times are display the 24 hours, how can i change the time to only display 09:00am - 06:00pm?

Thankyou.

Comment: What version of fullcalendar are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your uiconfig (from http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) and include **minTime** and **maxTime** in your uiconfig:

```
    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        minTime: '09:00:00', // Added mintime
        maxTime: '18:00:00' // Added maxtime
      }
    };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791219/fullcalendar-event-error-repeat-1-click-11-times please help me for another question, thankyou.

Comment: @MarCrazyness This is not working for me, is it version specific or something.

Comment: @DipeshParmar can you share a jsfiddle with me and what version of fullcalendar are you using?